# Tuples in C# 4.0 - passing class objects

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a function that returns a tuple made up of two objects of the same class.

```
class MyClass
{
     public int i;
     public char c;
};
```

Now, I have a function that returns IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<MyClass, MyClass>> Func1()
{
.....
.....

yield return Tuple.Create(MyClassObj1, MyClassObj2);
}
```

And I have one more function that access this tuple as a parameter.

```
public void Func2(Tuple<MyClass, MyClass> Pair)
{
   //here I can access Pair.Item1 and Pair.Item2 but not Pair.Item1.i or Pair.Item2.c    
}
```

Now, how do I access the member elements of the objects MyClassObj1 and MyClassObj2 inside Func2?

Answer (score 4):

> how do i access the member elements of the objects MyClassObj1 and MyClassObj2 inside Func2?

<strike>Make them `public` in the declaration of `MyClass`.</strike> The compiler error message should give some clues.

Comment: they are already public. Still, "Pair.Item1." does not give any intellisense

Comment: @Deepak, don't trust intellisense... only trust the compiler

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. I was using an older version of Visual Studio. I think tuples were not supported in C# 3.0